# Unity 2019.2.12f1 PlayerPrefs halting script

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, authentication

I am working on building out an authentication system for a project I am working on.

Part of this is to save UserData locally so that it doesn't have to connect to cloud on every run, or force a login ETC.

The problem i am having, is when i am trying to set PlayerPrefs it is not working. I have it running a Debug.Log before each PlayerPrefs.SetString and it only ever displays the first one.

I am able to do PlayerPrefs.SetString in my Start() but for some reason it is not working here and i have no idea why.

Everything works up until i am saving to PlayerPrefs

`public Dictionary<string, string> LoggedUser = new Dictionary<string, string>();`

```
public void getUserData(string id, string email)
    {
        Debug.Log("Getting User Data for ID: " + id);
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
            .GetReference(id)
            .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task1 =>
            {
                if (task1.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Failed");
                }
                else if (task1.IsCompleted)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Data Retrieved");
                    DataSnapshot snapshot = task1.Result;
                    foreach (DataSnapshot user in snapshot.Children)
                    {

                        string firstName = user.Child("firstName").Value.ToString();
                        string lastName = user.Child("lastName").Value.ToString();
                        string sex = user.Child("sex").Value.ToString();
                        string country = user.Child("country").Value.ToString();
                        string age = user.Child("age").Value.ToString();
                        string userName = user.Child("userName").Value.ToString();

                        Debug.Log(firstName);

                        LoggedUser.Add("FirstName", firstName);
                        LoggedUser.Add("LastName", lastName);
                        LoggedUser.Add("Email", email);
                        LoggedUser.Add("age", age);
                        LoggedUser.Add("sex", sex);
                        LoggedUser.Add("country", country);
                        LoggedUser.Add("userName", userName);


                        Debug.Log("Welcome " + LoggedUser["FirstName"]);
                        Debug.Log("User signed in successfully: " +newUser.Email +" " +newUser.UserId);
                        setPlayer();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

```
public void setPlayer()
    {
        Debug.Log("Saving to PlayerPrefs");
        Debug.Log("Setting First Name");
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("FirstName", "Ezekiel");
        Debug.Log("Setting Last Name");
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("LastName", LoggedUser["LastName"]);
        Debug.Log("Setting Email");
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Email", LoggedUser["Email"]);
        Debug.Log("Setting Age");
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("age", LoggedUser["age"]);
        Debug.Log("Setting Sex");
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("sex", LoggedUser["sex"]);
        Debug.Log("Setting Country");
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("country", LoggedUser["country"]);
        Debug.Log("Setting userName");
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("userName", LoggedUser["username"]);
        Debug.Log("Setting Loggedn State");
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LoggedIn", 1);
        Debug.Log("Saving Player Prefs");
        PlayerPrefs.Save();


        Debug.Log("Welcome " + PlayerPrefs.GetString("username"));
    }
```

Comment: PlayerPrefs.Save() writes data on the disk(e.g on pc it's hdd/ssd, on mobile it's internal storage (i know this info is 2*2=4 :D)). And maybe you don't have a permission on your machine to write the date from application, just try on other device or on other OS, otherwise everything looks fine in your code written above.

Comment: And also if I am wrong and there is not device permission issue, then you must search a problem in other scripts which are related to this one above(if there is any)

Comment: What kind of search problem? And I'm admin on the computer and it works in the start method of the same script

Comment: I mean your problem must be searched in other scripts not this one you posted here(that's only assumption) and where does it work? in editor or after build on actual device?

Comment: or what is your target platform?

Comment: In editor. Haven't tested in build

Comment: Target is Android and ios

Comment: just delete last line, playerperefs.save() and try, it may work

Comment: It doesn't even get that far though. It stops at seeing first name

Comment: lets delete setPlayer() in getUserData() and let me know what unity does

Comment: Without it there it wouldn't try to set them at all

Comment: I wonder it because to test if it crashes without using playerprefs

Comment: It never CRASHES persay, just doesnt execute the next lines of code. if i call the setPlayer() from start it works though. just not when i call it from the Firebase call.

Comment: `Firebase.Auth` should be preferred over a homemade solution, and caches the current user so you don't have to connect every run to authenticate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the solution.

getUserData() method is running async, which creats a new thread. the PlayerPrefs can only run on a main thread.

My solution was to create a boolean that i flippd to true when the Data was loaded into LoggedUser. my Update() method was watching for that to flip to true, where it then called the setPlayer().

Than you all for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind, I can expand on your answer a little bit.

If you use [ContinueWithOnMainThread](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension) instead of ContinueWith, your continuation logic automatically occurs on the main thread (so you can write `PlayerPrefs`). I cover a whole ton of ways to handle threading with Firebase and Unity in [this article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html) if you'd like to compare them.

Furthermore, this is a stab in the dark, but if you're using Realtime Database then you may also be using [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth). If this is the case, then [FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/firebase-auth#currentuser) actually persists between runs of your game (I cover this a little bit in [this video](https://youtu.be/52yUcKLMKX0)). Since Realtime Database also caches data you request locally, you may actually be doing extra work that the Firebase plugins will handle for you!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `userName`

> PlayerPrefs.SetString("userName", LoggedUser["username"]);

and retrieving `username`

> Debug.Log("Welcome " + PlayerPrefs.GetString("username"));

Also it should be

> PlayerPrefs.SetString("userName", LoggedUser["userName"]);

instead of

> PlayerPrefs.SetString("userName", LoggedUser["username"]);

[image]

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, i did notice that and have fixed it. however it was not the fix to my problem